# jQuery for opening url in Flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, actionscript, menu

I have a little problem with opening links because I was using script

```
getURL("javascript: $(function(){$('#SCT_InnerContent').load('"+_root.linksDB[id][2]+"?lang=en');});");
```

in flash but it works only in Google Chrome.
Can anyone help me with reworking this script to run under other browsers as well?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the jQuery into a JavaScript function in the page, and then call that using `ExternalInterface`? This is the most robust way of communicating with browser JavaScript from within Flash.

Something like this in the page:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function handleFlashCall(arg){ 
        $(function(){$('#SCT_InnerContent').load('"+ arg +"?lang=en');});
    }
</script>
```

And then, from within Flash:

```
ExternalInterface.call("handleFlashCall", _root.linksDB[id][2]);
```

See the explanation here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf626ae-7fe8.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f31

And reference docs here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call%28%29

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have allowScriptAccess flashvar parameter available and set to "always".  Take a look at the wrapper html to set it.

Take a look at [this](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/changes-allowscriptaccess-default-flash-player.html) documentation on the subject.